# Take value from textbox which is byte value and convert it to string in C#

Tags: c#

My value in textbox is  `"48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6c 64 21 00 00 00 00"` which is in byte format. How can I convert it to string format?

In short, if I enter bytes values in textbox, how can I convert it to string by clicking a button?

Comment: What is your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have an array of bytes representing ASCII codes that you want to turn into a string.

Give the byte array like so:

```
byte[] bytes = {0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

You can turn it into a string like so:

```
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

If we print this out, we discover that the text is:

```
Hello world!
```

But note that it has 4 ASCII NUL characters at the end of the string (the 0 values in the source bytes).

Also note that if the bytes represent ANSI codes in the current code page, you'd use:

```
string text = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

And if they represent UTF8 bytes you use:

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

To convert from a string of hex values to a byte array you can use one of the other answers in this topic, or use this:

```
string hexBytes = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6c 64 21 00 00 00 00";
byte[] bytes = hexBytes.Split(' ').Select(hex => byte.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```

Putting this all together into one compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hexBytes = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6c 64 21 00 00 00 00";
            byte[] bytes = hexBytes.Split(' ').Select(hex => byte.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  this worked for me -  string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

Answer (score 1):

Providing the string is Ascii one, you can try simple *Linq* query:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6c 64 21 00 00 00 00";

string result = new string(source
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(x => (char)Convert.ToInt32(x, 16))
  .ToArray());
```

Test

```
Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome

```
Hello world!
```